# Discord.js - Problem with the reaction collector

Tags: node.js, discord.js, emoji, collectors

Thats my code for a little function but user.id is everytime undefined. And I dont know why.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', function(message) {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content === prefix+'react'){
  message.react('');
  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id != bot.user.id;
  };
  
  const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 5000 });
  
  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    message.channel.send(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.id}`);
  });
  
  collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id !== bot.user.id;
};
```

something like this works for me